# SQL Server r2 installation error .. update Visual Studio 2008 to SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 r2. I keep on getting following error and not being able to install.

[image]

Then I visited the following link and corrected SP1 and 1 as indicated:

[Another version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 has been detected on this system that must be updated to SP1. Please update all Visual Studio 2008 installations to SP1 level, by visiting Microsoft Update.](http://sqlserverstore.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/another-version-of-microsoft-visual.html)

I even searched through my computer to find Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, but it doesn't exist.

Then I tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio Express with SP1. It also showed me the same error indicating the existance of the previous version os Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and asked me to update.

So, I visited the following link to install and update SP1:

[Download SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986)

Then it says me that there is no Visual Studio 2008 as follows

[image]

I am too much freaked out.

I am waiting impatiently if someone could come up with the solution and I am not being able to do anything with SQL server.

Thanx to both solvers and viewers.

Some other links I tried are:

[RemoveKB944899](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/RemoveKB944899)

[Using MsiInv to gather information about what is installed on a computer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/07/01/434814.aspx)

[Fix problems that programs cannot be installed or uninstalled](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)

None of these could be of any help to me.

Comment: Just doing a search on the title of your question leads to [SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio install fails telling me to install Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/baf09c3f-be97-4bc8-b6d7-bdeea2e3719e/sql-server-2008-r2-management-studio-install-fails-telling-me-to-install-visual-studio-2008-sp1?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade) among others.

Comment: Thanx Andrew, I appreciate your effort..

Comment: Hi, in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\9.0 the (Default) of type REG_SZ value should have been (value not set). But, when by mistake I set its value and later I deleted. Now instead of (value not set), its blank. Can it be the cause. How can I make it back to (value not set) instead of blank?

Answer (score 1):

> I used the [Visual Studio 2008 Uninstall tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=105801) and it worked fine for me.
>
> You can use this tool to uninstall Visual Studio 2008 official release and Visual Studio 2008 Release candidate (Only English version).
>
> Found here, on the MSDN Forum:  [MSDN forum topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d464ff4b-e1da-4b9f-bec7-4477e16f0350).

I found this answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/388023/354319)

Be sure you run the tool with admin-rights.

Comment: Please add some information into the body of your answer so it remains useful to others if the link changes or dies (i.e. SU question or answer getting deleted).

Comment: I wanted to be sure nobody had to think I did a lazy copy/paste to steal the credits, but you're right. I've edited my post.

Comment: As long as you provide the source, there souldn't be any problem. Thanks for editing.

Comment: The page links to the Visual Studio 2008 uninstall tool: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=105801

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I solved it. Even though the solution is a bit lengthy, I think its the simplest. The solution is as follows:

> 1. Install Visual Studio 2008
> 2. Install the service Package 1 (SP1)
> 3. Install SQL Server 2008 r2